# Error - "Corrupt JPEG data: 214 extraneous bytes before marker" after sending image to server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am sending image to server by converting the image into base64 format. But the probelm is after sending the image string the character '+' is replacing by a blank space " ". And there is showing the error:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 214 extraneous bytes before marker
```

How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the image conversion code into base64 format:

```
-(NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
NSInteger length = [theData length];

static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

NSInteger i;
for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
    NSInteger value = 0;
    NSInteger j;
    for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
        value <<= 8;

        if (j < length) {
            value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
        }
    }

    NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
    output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
    output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
    output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
}

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Here is the code for converting into Json format & sending that into server:

```
-(void)setOflynData2JsonFormat{

if (!([self.getOfflineData count] == 0)) {

    NSArray *array = [self getOfflineData];

    arrayOfJsonString = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i<[array count]; i++) {

        uniqueId++;

        NSNumber *uId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:uniqueId];

        OfflineTableObject *offObj = [array objectAtIndex:i];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        [dict setValue:uId forKey:@"id"];
        [dict setValue:offObj.qrCode forKey:@"qrCode"];
        [dict setValue:offObj.offlineStatus forKey:@"activity"];
        [dict setValue:offObj.time forKey:@"time"];
        [dict setValue:offObj.imageData forKey:@"image_base64"];


        [arrayOfJsonString addObject:dict];

    }

    NSData * jsonDataFromArray = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayOfJsonString
                                                        options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:nil];


    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDataFromArray encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //replace backslash from string
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] init];

    NSString *specialChar = @"\\";

    jsonString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:specialChar withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"sent string to server: %@",jsonString);

    int lng = [jsonString length];

    NSLog(@"2nd string length: %d",lng);


    Get_Object_Class *obj = [[Get_Object_Class alloc]init];

    NSString *dvid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];

    [obj sendDeviceId:dvid];

    NSLog(@"device id: %@",dvid);


    int check = [obj sendOfflynData2Server:jsonString];

    if (check == 1) {

        NSLog(@"Offline data uploaded");

        AppDelegate *test = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];

        [test resetOfflineTable];
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Offline data upload failed");
    }

}

else{

    NSLog(@"Offline table is empty");
}

}

-(BOOL)sendOfflynData2Server:(NSString *)jsonRequest{

NSHTTPURLResponse * response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;

NSString * post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&offline_data=%@",jsonRequest];

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@saveofflinedata.php", APIheader]]];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:jsonRequest forHTTPHeaderField:@"offline_data"];


NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSData *dataReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSString *stringReply = (NSString *)[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

stringReply = [stringReply stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"["];
stringReply = [stringReply stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"]"];
stringReply = [stringReply stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"stringReply: %@", stringReply);

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
NSArray *array = [parser objectWithString:stringReply error:nil];
stringReply = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"success"]];


NSLog(@"Success: %@", stringReply);

return [stringReply intValue];


}
```

Here is the string i am sending to server:

```
        NSString * str1 = @"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";
```

And this is the string showing in server:

```
    NSString *str2 = @"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 Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3 Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3 Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDeprtgdQPc1FdXUdrCZJD9B3JrnZ76S4lLO5C9lB4oEb3nLu4kzTvP2981zq3gTpxT/tp65pDN2e4VogO5NQBFchiASOmaz1ud5Xmr8ByvFAF 3IEQ 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 KYXJNPaCU87DUflSD A/lUljg9OD81H5b/3T VGCD0NAXJw3FOXmolRm6KT FTLHJ/cNKw7liyXNwD6DNaNQ6fbMELMMFqtPEw6VaIZHRThE57U7yX9KBEdJU4tz3NL9m/2qBleipjbt7UUASeQnpTDaoewqeloAqm0T0FN wx56CrlFMCBLWNewp4hQdqkooEAAHSiiigYUtFFABRRRQAUUUUANNHaiigQCloopAFFFFMYUUUUALRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAH//2Q==";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `+` signs aren't URL encoded in the post data even though your content type says they are.

You'll need to replace them by `%2B` for the recipient to get them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just convert your UIImage into NSData and your NSData to base64?

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
NSString *base64string = [imageData base64EncodedString];
```

Just implement one of many NSData categories like this one: https://github.com/l4u/NSData-Base64